# Has 'kUTTypeFlatRTFD' been renamed?

Tags: ios, swift, pasteboard

When trying to access the constant `kUTTypeFlatRTFD` (or any of the text types for that matter) I get the issue that it is an unresolved identifier.

It appears to not be deprecated, and available as part of MobileCoreServices:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/mobilecoreservices/kuttypeflatrtfd

Currently, even the simple `print(kUTTypeFlatRTFD);` results in this compiler error when placed in a blank view controller of a new iOS project.

Is there a special way to access this in Swift 3+?

Comment: It seems to work for me. Did you `import MobileCoreServices`?

Comment: Is that not imported by default?

Comment: Nothing is really imported by default - normally you import UIKit or something like that at the top of your file. Perhaps importing UIKit imports that implicitly, but I don't think so.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarity. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Sure thing - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a type or constant, make sure you have imported the relevant library. For your case, `import MobileCoreServices` should do the trick.

Normally, you will `import Foundation` or `import UIKit` at the top of a Swift file (for iOS projects anyway). If what you need isn't contained in that library you need to explicitly import it.